# What is the matrix representation of the Hadamard gate in the computational basis?

Tags: quantum-gate, textbook-and-exercises, hadamard

I read about Hadamard gate H and found it's matrix representation as follows:

$$H_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$

I wanted to know what will be the matrix representation of H in computational basis.

Comment: Welcome on the QC SE! We have quite good Latex support here, but we don't really like screenshots. I don't know if your passes well this site, but if it is a border case, your chances are hugely increased by if you use Latex formulas.

Answer (score 4):

This *is* the matrix representation of $H$ in the computational basis. The first column is the image of $|0\rangle$ and the second column is the image of $|1\rangle$.

The reason that $H$ looks the same in both the computational and the "plus/minus" basis is that $H$ is a *self-adjoint* (or hermitian) unitary, this makes it very special as it means that its self-inverse since we have that $$H^{−1}=H^\dagger=H\,.$$

Comment: So, if this is the matrix representation of H in the computational basis, then what is the matrix representation of H in the hadamard basis? Thanks

Comment: It's just the matrix whose columns are the image of $H|+\rangle$ and $H|-\rangle$